# Matching date and time from mysql - logic issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded a PHP script in the server. What it does is, that it keeps reading the DB (mySQL), and if the `DATE_OF_MATCH` and `TIME_OF_MATCH` (these are 2 fields in the mySQL db) is equal to the server time it will execute a message.

fields in the table: all are `VARCHAR`

```
ID, DATE_OF_MATCH, TIME_OF_MATCH, MATCH_NAME
```

One record from the `MATCH` table;

```
1 , 1/12/2012, 3:40, ManU vs Kaks
```

The problem is that, my select statement is wrong. My `$theDateAndTime` is returning `09:15:03PM` and in the Database i am having 2 separate records for date and time. So how can i edit the select statement so could match the date and time against the  `$theDateAndTime` (returned by the server)

The code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$theDateAndTime = date("h:i:sA")."\n";



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MATCH where DATE_OF_MATCH=".$theDateAndTime." and TIME_OF_MATCH=".$theDateAndTime."");

while(true){
if(result!=null){

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['MATCH_NAME'] ;
  echo "<br />";
  }
}
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You aren't quoting the parameter in your SQL, nor are you escaping it (not that `date` is going to return much that needs escaping).  Also: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).  It happens that using the parameterized placeholders provided by either of those options would totally avoid the problem you're having here.

Comment: did you try using date(.$theDateAndTime) and Time(.$theDateAndTime) . DATE() AND TIME() are mysql function. sorry i dont know php so there might be some syntax errors. REFER http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well, but seems that you are trying to query for date and time in two different fields but you are only take the current time. I think you should try something like this:

```
<?php
$current_date = date('d/m/Y');
$current_time = date('h:i');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MATCH where DATE_OF_MATCH=".$current_date." and TIME_OF_MATCH=".$current_time."");
```

Otherwise, you should not use mysql_* functions, use mysqli_* functions instead with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate variables for date and then time.

```
$the_date = date("n/j/Y");
$the_time = date("h:i:s");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MATCH where DATE_OF_MATCH={$the_date} and TIME_OF_MATCH={$the_time}");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php